# Codenameone getting the byte[] of a file

Tags: image, capture, codenameone

After this line:

```
String photoFileLocation = Capture.capturePhoto();
```

I want to transmit such image to a server. How Can I get the bytes[] of the file which name is in the variable 'photoFileLocation'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FileSystemStorage` to open files.

But for actual file upload you should use `MultipartRequest` which accepts file URL's (more efficient than reading bytes). You can see an example of this including the server code in the recent workshop we released https://www.codenameone.com/blog/build-mobile-ios-apps-in-java-using-codename-one-on-youtube.html

You can see a full sample in the JavaDoc for multipart request here: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/MultipartRequest.html

Comment: That link predated a website change (it was from 6 years ago) added html and changed to https and it works now. Also added a newer link below